# Multi- Class probabilities of Random Forest inside caret Model

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, multinomial-distribution, caret

Im facing a problem with the results of a multi-class random forest model.

I want to use a) the predictions of the model and b) the class probabilities of these predictions for further work.

I did a cross-validation, grouped by a variable I dismissed right after, and trained a multiclass model, using the following code:

```
folds5 <- groupKFold(feature_data$hh_id, k = 5) 
#remove group variable
feature_data <- feature_data[, ! names(feature_data) == "hh_id"]


fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                           number = 5,
                           index = folds5,
                           sampling = "down",
                           savePred=T)

set.seed(1)
rf_mod <- train(class~.,feature_data,
                method = "rf",
                norm.votes=T,
                #predict.all=FALSE,
                type = "Classification",
                metric= "Accuracy",
                ntree = 500,
                trControl = fitControl)
```

my results is an accuracy of approx 40%, which is reasonable for that case. this is the confusion matrix:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   1   2   3   4   5
         1 245 399  61  57  37
         2 171 962 162 206  91
         3  50 456 131 130  51
         4  36 352  95 395 167
         5  67 182  42 263 152

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.38
```

My first thoughts to continue was to use the function `predict(..., type = "prob")` to get the probabilities.
This leads to accuracy going up to 80%. I suppose that these results are wrong, because the data was also used for learning.

```
predict_rf_model <- predict(rf_mod)

caret::confusionMatrix(predict_rf_model , feature_data$class)

          Reference
Prediction    1    2    3    4    5
         1  558  190    0   13    0
         2    8 1658    0   45    0
         3    1  221  491   54    2
         4    1  185    0  886    1
         5    1   97    0   53  495

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.8242          
                 95% CI : (0.8133, 0.8347)
```

This means I cannot use predict() to get the class probabilites

I was trying to find fields inside my model `rf_mod`. And I found some promising fields:

- `rf_mod$pred` saves the predictions of all test samples, if you set safePred in TrainControl. By that I get all predicted classes, which is nice
- there is a field `rf_mod$finalModel$votes` which saves the class probabilities( 5 Classes) :

```
> rf_mod$finalModel$votes
               1           2           3           4           5
1    0.521505376 0.021505376 0.010752688 0.064516129 0.381720430
2    0.865979381 0.072164948 0.020618557 0.005154639 0.036082474
3    0.873626374 0.054945055 0.038461538 0.016483516 0.016483516
...
```

- I first thought this is what I need, but finalModel has the same or a similar confusion matrix as the predict function() with falsified(?) results.

Where can I get the classifier probability like in `rf_mod$finalModel$votes`? 
There might be another parameter to get the probabilites that I am too dumb to figure out.

Any other solution to get class probabilities with grouped cross validation is also appreciated.

For your interest, I want to combine the classifier results in the next step, by hh_id. An information about the probability could improve the results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `savePredictions`, you should set `classProbs=TRUE`.

https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/trainControl.html
https://stackoverflow.com/q/36750272/10495893

Answer (score 0):

this works, thanks a lot. The method is creating an error:

"Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names (see ?make.names for help)."

To fix this I had to rename my goal variables. Results looking way more realistic. 
The result is in the same object:

```
rf_mod$pred
     pred obs   one   two three  four  five rowIndex mtry Resample
1     one one 0.458 0.274 0.110 0.122 0.036        3    2    Fold1
2     two one 0.274 0.364 0.146 0.164 0.052        5    2    Fold1
3    five one 0.236 0.188 0.022 0.110 0.444        6    2    Fold1
4     one one 0.334 0.244 0.254 0.022 0.146        7    2    Fold1
5     two one 0.360 0.412 0.092 0.084 0.052        8    2    Fold1
...
```